# What is the possible solution for this code [Python 3.x]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n_players = int(input('Welcome to the game, please tell me how many players will play: '))

print('Now tell me the names of the ', n_players, ' players')

for i in range(0, n_players):
    player_i = input('Enter the name of player',i)
```

The problem is in the last line where the compiler tell me that exist an error :/
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` function can not receive more than one argument, you need to interpolate:

```
player_list.append(input('Enter the name of player {}'.format(i + 1)))
```

Comment: Thanx so much :D Your answer looks the ¡easier way to solve my problem jeje

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for get player names:

```
player_names = []
for i in range(n_players):
    player_i = input('Enter the name of player {}: '.format(i + 1))
    player_names.append(player_i)
```

Comment: Making it `'Enter the name of player {}: '.format(i + 1)` will make the message more readable IMO; `Enter the name of 1-th player`, `Enter the name of 2-th player` sounds odd.

Answer (score 0):

The input function takes a single string as an argument, not like print which can take many items.